# Unable to click on graph with lower values to see data in CRM 2015

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have graph created in CRM as seen in the picture below. I am unable to click and view data for bars with lower values ( For ex: I am unable to click on values 1s, 2s and 14 whereas I am able to click and view data for bigger values )

Also I am able to click and see data for lower values in Stack graph not in bar graph.

** It doesn't matter the territory holder or quarter, its for all the values below 15.

Is there anything I can do, to be able to click  and view data related to bars with lower values ?

[CRM Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/risu4.jpg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that those columns are just simply too small. You could play with the xml of your chart and add some scale breaks. It should make those columns bigger and available for clicking.

Have a look here to learn about scale breaks: https://crmchartguy.wordpress.com/category/scalebreak/